# How to call SharePoint Online from mobile app via webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, windows-runtime, office365

I have client app written in WindowsRT which connects with SharePoint Office365 server trough webservices. The way I am doing this now Is sending user name and password to webservices and then they authenticate with SharePoint, get data and pass back to client app.

```
_clientContext = new ClientContext(hostUrl) 
{ 
Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword) 
};
```

Could anyone provide some idea/spec/link which will explain how to avoid sending username and password with every request to webservices. I want to replace them with authentication token the way that client app would receive auth token from SharePoint server then pass it to webservice, which will use it to communicate with SharePoint on my behalf? Because is not nice/secure to send user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send the password, it is encrypted, you're not sending password as plain text.

You can use OAuth for SharePoint online, this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687470%28v=office.15%29.aspx) provides the flow.